# RXKotlin Lambda Understanding

Tags: lambda, kotlin, rx-kotlin

This never completes:

```
Completable.complete()
        .andThen{ Completable.complete() }
        .test()
        .assertComplete()
```

This does complete:

```
Completable.complete()
        .andThen(Completable.complete())
        .test()
        .assertComplete()
```

According to Jake Wharton:

"You want `andThen(Completable.complete())`. Note the use of parenthesis and
not curly braces. The latter creates a lambda that doesn't call its emitter."

Reference: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5551

Can anyone explain this in more detail? I thought I understood lambda's but this has really thrown me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the curly braces, you're using [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) and defining an anonymous `CompletableSource` instance by describing its single method inside the lambda.

This is the same as doing the following:

```
Completable.complete()
        .andThen(object: CompletableSource {
            override fun subscribe(cs: CompletableObserver) {
                Completable.complete()
            }
        })
        .test()
        .assertComplete()
```

As you can see, inside this `CompletableSource` you're doing nothing but creating a `Completable` instance and throwing away its result. For the chain to continue, you'd have to call methods on the `CompleteableObserver` that you've received as a parameter (for example, you could call `onNext()` and `onComplete()` on it).

---

Although it's almost the same syntax, here's the Java version, in case it helps you understand things:

```
Completable.complete()
        .andThen(new CompletableSource() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(CompletableObserver cs) {
                Completable.complete();
            }
        })
        .test()
        .assertComplete();
```

Comment: Great great explanation, I must have been very tired, this makes complete sense.

Comment: It's one of those gotchas that everyone using Kotlin and Rx are bound to spend a couple hours debugging, unfortunately. It happens with other Rx classes and operators too.

Comment: Brain melt :D it's the same thing that's hurting my brain trying to learn Haskell

Answer (score 1):

1. The valid example in parentheses works as follows:

   `Completable.complete()` is executed and then passed as an argument to `andThen`.
2. The invalid one does simply pass a lambda in curly braces as an argument to `andThen`, which becomes an implementation (thanks to [SAM Conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)) of [`CompletableSource`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/CompletableSource.html). It never gets executed. The following shows what you do:

   ```
   val compl = CompletableSource { Completable.complete() }
   Completable.complete()
       .andThen (compl)
       .test()
       .assertComplete()
       .assertComplete()
   ```